# Update several ppt files from a single excel file

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have several ppt files and a single excel file containing the same information. I want all ppt files to be updated automatically whenever I change the information in the excel file. The reason is that the information is changing regularly and I want to avoid that it has to be changed in all the files manually every time. Instead, it should be possible to update all the files just by changing the excel.

Do you know, how I could do this?

Thanks and regards,
Marius

Comment: If the information is in the form of a spreadsheet or chart, you can link those from Excel. If it's textual information or individual cells, you could use a VBA macro to do the job. Search on _Excel VBA update PowerPoint information_ to find macros that are a starting point.

Comment: Many thanks, this looks great on the first glance! I will have a more detailed look when I find the time. But is there really no other option than using VBA?